# SVG transform property not taking acount in IE Edge

Tags: html, css, svg

The JSFiddle below is an SVG drawing, with 2 brown rectangle `<rect>` spaced each other and that have both a group `<g>` that have a class `class="group"` which applies a transformation (rotation and translation).

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hf7k6pbd/3/)

Refering Caniuse.com, that gave most of the support rate for major browsers, it shows that IE9+ support SVG transform property, and it says on *Know issues* :

> IE 10 and below does not support CSS transforms on SVG elements (though SVG transform attributes do work).

**QUESTION**

Despite the fact my only source is this website, I would know if we figured out why IE Edge does not support transform property at this time (**december 2015**) ?

**QUESTION 2**

Is there any alternative to apply a CSS transformation which would be supported by IE (Edge), Chrome and Firefox ?

**NOTE**

JSFiddle tested successfuly on Chrome and Firefox. Only IE fails the test in both version (5, 7, 8, 9, 10, Edge).

Comment: For question 2, I think one option would be try and wrap the element in a `div` and apply the required transform to the `div`.

Comment: For the answer to Q1... *ask Microsoft*.

Comment: Question 1 is something we've all asked about a lot of things unsupported in IE/Edge for a decade or more and will probably still be asking a decade from now.

Comment: Still an issue in Edge as of August 2017

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through CSS, I think it's not supported in IE or Edge.

The attribute is working, I have  tested that, so I think we have to change the method of implementation.

```
<g class="group" transform ="translate(100, 100) rotate(90)">
```

Do it manually or, if `<g class="group">` is already created, then use javascript or jquery for append this attribute to `<g class="group">`

**Snippet**

```html
<svg width="500px" height="500px">
  <g class="group" transform ="translate(100, 100) rotate(90)">
    <rect width="100px" height="10px" fill="brown"></rect>
    <rect x="50px" y="50px" width="100px" height="10px" fill="brown"></rect>
  </g> 
</svg>
```

Comment: svg tutorial is use full for you http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-transformation.html

Comment: Thanks @code.rider, I just figured out I had some other CSS properties that overrided the transform attribute, thanks a lot for your input by the way, everything works like a charm !